# Milo OPC UA UaException: status=Bad_UnexpectedError

Tags: scala, opc-ua, opc, milo

I am trying to call a method "Multiply" from a FolderType that has the method "Multiply" and multiply e.g. 2 * 5 and get the result.

But I get the following error message when executing the program:

UaException: status=Bad_UnexpectedError, message=java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaSerializationException: unknown builtin type: -1

I have absolutely no idea why.

This is my code

```
val loadedConfig   : Config        = ConfigFactory.parseFile ( new File ( path ) )
val namespaceIndex : Int           = loadedConfig.getInt ( "namespaceIndex" )
val nodeID         : String        = loadedConfig.getString ( "nodeId" )
val readMethodId   : QualifiedName = new QualifiedName ( QualifiedNameIndex, Read )
val Read           : String        = loadedConfig.getString ( "readMethodId" )

val client : Option [ OpcUaClient ] = new OpcConnector ( config = loadedConfig ).createOpcClients ( )

read ( nodeId = nodeId,
       readMethodId = readMethodId,
       multiply = 5 )

private def read ( nodeId : NodeId, readMethodId : QualifiedName, multiply : Int ) : Unit = {


  val method : UaMethod = client
    .get
    .getAddressSpace.getObjectNode ( nodeId )
    .getMethod ( readMethodId )

  val inputs : Array [ Variant ] = Array ( new Variant ( multiply , 2 ) )

  val outputs : AnyRef = method.call ( inputs ) 

  println ( "result: " + outputs )
}
```

Both the OPC address and the node are correct.

Milo OPC 0.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `val inputs : Array [ Variant ] = Array ( new Variant ( multiply , 2 ) )`

What is this line supposed to be doing? There is no Variant constructor that takes 2 args.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the line is correct with `val inputs : Array [ Variant ] = Array ( new Variant ( multiply), new Variant (2) )`. 
The problem has been solved, thank you for your support.

Comment: I suspect you were previously creating some kind of implicit tuple value that was not recognized by Milo's encoder, but I'm not familiar enough with Scala syntax any more to know for sure.